# Two different plots from same loop in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I would specifically like to create two different plots using **one single loop**. One plot should have four straight lines from x-y, and another plot should have four angled lines from x-y2. My code only shows everything in a single plot. I don't quite understand how plt works, how can I create two distinct plt objects?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2

x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
y2=[[11,12,13,24],[42,33,34,65],[23,54,65,86],[77,90,39,54]]
colours=['r','g','b','k']

for i in range(len(x)):
   plt.plot(x[i],y2[i],colours[i])
   plt2.plot(x[i],y[i],colours[i])

plt.show()
plt2.show()
```

Comment: create two separate figure objects e.g. by `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()`, `fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()`, then plot with `ax1.plot` and `ax2.plot`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is that what you want to do?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
y2=[[11,12,13,24],[42,33,34,65],[23,54,65,86],[77,90,39,54]]
colours=['r','g','b','k']

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax1.plot(x[i],y2[i],colours[i])
    ax2.plot(x[i],y[i],colours[i])

fig1.show()
fig2.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain how to best add title and legends in this loop?