# Improving for loop performance and customizing graphs

Tags: python

I have created a code that returns the output that I am after - 2 graphs with multiple lines on each graph. However, the code is slow and quite big (in terms of how many lines of code it takes). I am interested in any improvements I can make that will help me to get such graphs faster, and make my code more presentable.

Additionally, I would like to add more to my graphs (axis names and titles is what I am after). Normally, I would use `plt.xlabel`,`plt.ylabel` and `plt.title` to do so, however I couldn't quite understand how to use them here. The aim here is to add a line to each graph after each loop ( I have adapted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309261/two-different-plots-from-same-loop-in-matplotlib) piece of code to do so).

I should note that I need to use Python for this task (so I cannot change to anything else) and I do need Sympy library to find values that are plotted in my graphs.

My code so far is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

sym.init_printing()
x, y = sym.symbols('x, y') # defining our unknown probabilities
al = np.arange(20,1000,5).reshape((196,1)) # values of alpha/beta
prob_of_strA = []
prob_of_strB = []
colours=['r','g','b','k','y']
pen_values = [[0,-5,-10,-25,-50],[0,-25,-50,-125,-250]]
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
for j in range(0,len(pen_values[1])):
    for i in range(0,len(al)): # choosing the value of beta

        A = sym.Matrix([[10, 50], [int(al[i]), pen_values[0][j]]]) # defining matrix A
        B = sym.Matrix([[pen_values[1][j], 50], [int(al[i]), 10]]) # defining matrix B
        sigma_r = sym.Matrix([[x, 1-x]]) # defining the vector of probabilities 
        sigma_c = sym.Matrix([y, 1-y]) # defining the vector of probabilities 
        ts1 = A * sigma_c ; ts2 = sigma_r * B # defining our utilities 

        y_sol = sym.solvers.solve(ts1[0] - ts1[1],y,dict = True) # solving for y
        x_sol = sym.solvers.solve(ts2[0] - ts2[1],x,dict = True) # solving for x
        prob_of_strA.append(y_sol[0][y]) # adding the value of y to the vector
        prob_of_strB.append(x_sol[0][x]) # adding the value of x to the vector
    ax1.plot(al,prob_of_strA,colours[j],label = ["penalty = " + str(pen_values[0][j])]) # plotting value of y for a given penalty value
    ax2.plot(al,prob_of_strB,colours[j],label = ["penalty = " + str(pen_values[1][j])]) # plotting value of x for a given penalty value
    ax1.legend() # showing the legend
    ax2.legend() # showing the legend
    prob_of_strA = [] # emptying the vector for the next round
    prob_of_strB = [] # emptying the vector for the next round
```

Comment: What are you gaining through the use of Sympy? It's not fast.

Comment: You may want to consider using Cython, PyPy, or Numba JIT for massive python for loops. Or consider switching to Julia.

Comment: @sjc I need it to find values of x and y. Simply putting I am using it to solve system of linear equations that come from multiplying matricies A and B by vectors that have y/x in them (which are unknown).

Comment: You'll be much better off re-writing this with Numpy functions, which are faster than Sympy. You'll probably be able to vectorize it such that you remove the inner loop, too, which buys you additional speedup

Comment: @sjc Your answer works (your 2nd for loop was 1 space wrong but otherwise it worked). I figured out how to add title/axis, so I am happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: That saved you four lines, but otherwise wasn't really transformative. I still think you'd be better served by using `numpy.linalg`, so if someone beats me to the punch there you can accept their answer.

Comment: If it's about improving working code, you want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a couple of lines by initializing your empty vectors inside the loop. You don't have to bother re-defining them at the end.

```
for j in range(0,len(pen_values[1])):
    prob_of_strA = []
    prob_of_strB = []

   for i in range(0,len(al)): # choosing the value of beta

        A = sym.Matrix([[10, 50], [int(al[i]), pen_values[0][j]]]) # defining matrix A
        B = sym.Matrix([[pen_values[1][j], 50], [int(al[i]), 10]]) # defining matrix B
        sigma_r = sym.Matrix([[x, 1-x]]) # defining the vector of probabilities 
        sigma_c = sym.Matrix([y, 1-y]) # defining the vector of probabilities 
        ts1 = A * sigma_c ; ts2 = sigma_r * B # defining our utilities 

        y_sol = sym.solvers.solve(ts1[0] - ts1[1],y,dict = True) # solving for y
        x_sol = sym.solvers.solve(ts2[0] - ts2[1],x,dict = True) # solving for x
        prob_of_strA.append(y_sol[0][y]) # adding the value of y to the vector
        prob_of_strB.append(x_sol[0][x]) # adding the value of x to the vector

    ax1.plot(al,prob_of_strA,colours[j],label = ["penalty = " + str(pen_values[0][j])]) # plotting value of y for a given penalty value
    ax2.plot(al,prob_of_strB,colours[j],label = ["penalty = " + str(pen_values[1][j])]) # plotting value of x for a given penalty value
    ax1.legend() # showing the legend
    ax2.legend() # showing the legend
```